# Import syntax for reference to dgrid from TypeScript

Tags: typescript, js-amd, dgrid

I am learning TypeScript and Dojo in parallel and this has exposed my limited understanding of AMD. I do not understand how to tie together an import statement to the 3rd party "dgrid/Grid" AMD module, my dgrid.d.ts stub declaration and my consuming class. After 2 days of wasted effort I am looking for any means (hacky or amd best practice) to execute the following:

**MyModule.ts**

```
{
    ...
    var myGrid = new dgrid.Grid( { /*col structure*/}, "divId");
    ...
}
```

Here is my stub declaration file for dgrid.

**dgrid.d.ts** (edited to sync with Update 1 below)

```
module "dgrid/Grid"
{
    export class Grid
    {
        constructor ( gridStructure: any, elementId: string);
    }
}
```

I tried the following references in my consuming TypeScript class but Visual Studio underlines the "dgrid/Grid" literal in red because I guess the TS compiler is unaware of the classic Dojo dojoConfig, baseUrl and dgrid package declarations in the default.htm file.

```
///<reference path='dgrid.d.ts' />

import Grid = module("dgrid/Grid");

module MyModule
{
   ...
}
```

**Update 1**
Since posting I read through chapter 10 in the official TypeScript manual. Previously I had failed to recognise the significance of modules declared as module MyType{} or module "external/thirdparty" {}. An ambient declaration for an external module should be a literal.

**Background:**

- I am using Dojo 1.8.0 referenced from ajax.googleapis.com
- The dgrid JavaScript is hosted locally in /js/dgrid
- I am trying to closely follow the SitePen dgrid tutorial
  page showing classic AMD require() loading of dgrid
  http://dojofoundation.org/packages/dgrid/tutorials/hello_dgrid http://dojofoundation.org/packages/dgrid/tutorials/hello_dgrid/demo/simple.html

Require statement:

```
require(["dgrid/Grid", "dojo/domReady!"],
    function(Grid){
```

Comment: No working solution yet. I have not abandoned this question, the TypeScript import statement is generating AMD style module code loading code but it does not materialize the loaded module into new(abe) types. I see the whole module namespace sitting under the prototype. I will post another SO question to cover this problem.

Comment: Okay. Can you post a link to that question here?

Answer (score 1):

The following (slightly changed) version of your code compiles fine for me:

**MyModule.ts**

```
///<reference path='./dgrid.d.ts' />
module MyModule {
    var gridInstance : dgrid.Grid = new dgrid.Grid("test1", "test2");
}
```

**dgrid.d.ts**

```
module dgrid
{
    class Grid
    {   
        constructor ( gridStructure: any, elementId: string);
    }   

}
```

The `///<reference path='...'/>` construct brings the *internal* module `dgrid` into scope. Prefixing the type name with the name of the module does the job.

Answer (score 0):

My first though would be to check that the file is in the locations you think it is for this statement to work:

```
///<reference path='dgrid.d.ts' />
```

Is the `dgrid.d.ts` file in the same folder as your module .ts file?

**Update:**

Should you module declaration be:

```
module dgrid {
    export class Grid {
        constructor ( gridStructure: any, elementId: string) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes all my .ts and .d.ts files are in the same directory and thanks for the edits to my OP. Following "Update 1" in my OP the compiler is generating var Dgrid = require("dgrid/Grid") but now I get a runtime Dojo exception as the require() executes. The compiler also exits with code "9009" which VS2012 treats as an error.

Comment: I have added a change to your module too.

Comment: @self The 9009 compiler exit code was because my hand editing of the tcs command in the .csproj was wrong. The compiler "amd" option expressed in the project file is sensitive to location and spacining. This works TypeScript\0.8.0.0\tsc&quot; --module amd @(TypeScriptCompile

Comment: @camelCase See my answer below. The issue is that you are using an internal module which is **not** imported but has to be brought into scope.

Comment: @Valentin your suggestion represents where I was at earlier this week. It works for the core Dojo grid dojox.Grid.DataGrid but fails to load the new semi official SitePen dgrid. Also I was trying adopt full modern AMD usage in my code after reading that fully namespaced references are an AMD code smell.